# Use blender model in ARToolkit but cannot display the materials. Why?

Tags: blender, artoolkit

I use blender to create a model like an apple like this:
[The model in Blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sz9aD.png)

And I export the model, getting a .obj file and a .mtl file, then I copy those two files into the folder of ARToolkit - examples/.../models - and change the setting in models.dat file by adding this:

models/Apple.obj
0.0 0.0 0.0
90.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
10.016 10.016 10.016
MARKER 1

But the model display without material like this:
[The rendering effect seen in the camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWmCv.jpg)

What should I do to display the model with material?

Answer (score 0):

you didn't provide a lot of information. But from the information I can see you can try the following.
Sometimes the textures in the material are switched so you can try and load the obj using this function:

glmReadOBJ3(model0file, 0, 0,true); // context 0, don't read textures yet.
The last parameter forces the rendering to flip the texture when rendering which might help in your case.

Documentation for this function is here: 
https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit5/blob/master/include/Eden/glm.h#L386

Let me know if that works for you.